# How to translate to Linq Expression

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have the following sql command which i cant translate into linq

```
select Distinct(fp.Parks_Id)
from ParkFeaturePark fp
Inner Join Parkfeatures feat on fp.ParkFeatures_Id = feat.Id
Inner Join Parks p On fp.Parks_Id = p.Id
where  p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =1 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =2 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =31     )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =42 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =106 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =118 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =4 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =6 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =10 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =18 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =22 )
    And p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =46 )
```

The twist here is that.. i have to use the combination seleted by the user .. sample is

```
    p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =1 )
    AND p.Id In (Select Parks_Id from ParkFeaturePark where ParkFeatures_Id =4 )
```

Or any other combination choose by the user..

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you've got navigation properties `Park.ParkFeatureParks` and `ParkFeaturePark.Parkfeatures`. (Or else will be able to create them). Then you can do:

```
int[] featureIds = new { 1, 2, 31, 42, 106, 118, .. };

var query = from p in context.Parks
            where p.ParkFeatureParks
                   .SelectMany(pfp => pfp.Parkfeatures)
                   .All(feature => featureIds
                                   .Contains(id => feature.ParkFeatures_Id))
            select p.Parks_Id;
```

Comment: thanks Gert, but my  problem is, i want to get those Park_id that have all those featureId passed to it, like ... I want those Id that has 1, 2, 10 featureId. And not  those park which only have 1 and 2 featureId.. sorry for my bad english.. hope you get what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer, but the good style coding -

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fp.Parks_Id)
FROM dbo.ParkFeaturePark fp
JOIN dbo.Parkfeatures feat ON fp.ParkFeatures_Id = feat.Id
JOIN dbo.Parks p ON fp.Parks_Id = p.Id
WHERE p.Id IN (
        SELECT Parks_Id 
        FROM dbo.ParkFeaturePark 
        WHERE ParkFeatures_Id IN (1, 2, 31, 42, 106, 118, 4, 6, 10, 18, 22, 46)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks devart, that somehow give me an idea

Comment: Im thinking about making the "where" to be dynamic using the Predicate Builder.. but can it be done without using it?